# Text Area stops scrolling after 28 lines

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a chat application as part of a coursework. I am using a text area to display sent and received messages, however it stops scrolling after 28 lines of text. How can I fix this?

Current code:

```
chatHistory = new TextArea();
chatHistory.setWrapText(true);
chatHistory.setEditable(true);
```

I have tried setting the prefNumberOfRows but it had no effect.

Comment: Could you add some more code to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This *could* be an issue with the pane your text area is inside, which may just crop the text area instead of adding a scrollbar to it.

Comment: Found the issue! I set the height of the content in my stylesheet. Removing pref-height below removed the scroll limit.
.chat-history .content {
        -fx-pref-height: 725;
        }

Comment: add following code **ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
 scrollPane.setContent(chatHistory );**